# Read/Parse File

Tags: c, file, parsing, file-handling

Recently I saw a piece of code here and I just wanted to change it up so see how I would read multiple lines through a file. Lets say the file has the following:

```
3 5 2 2 0 4 6 4 4 1 3 4 5 0 4 5 6 2 0 0 1 
4 0 1 2 0 3 1 4 1 0 0 1 2 3
```

So it parses just singular line, but I would like to do another line.

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, fp))
{
    if(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';

    while((result = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        //removes the end newline and replaces with a null
        if(fileContents[strlen(fileContents) - 1] == '\n')
            fileContents[strlen(fileContents) - 1] = '\0';

        //if a digit is in place and has been updated
        //then count++ and go ahead and store the result in an
        //Array, which will minus ASCII value 48 to get our #
        if( isdigit( result )  )
        {
            if( currentState == NOT_IN_NUMBER )
            { 
                //debug statement
                //printf("ASCII = %d\n",result);
                //minus 48 to get to our base 10 ints
                numberArray[count++] = result - 48;
                if(count == 1)
                {
                    how_many_page = result - 48;
                }
                //count++;
                currentState = IN_NUMBER; //Jp
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //a space is found
            currentState = NOT_IN_NUMBER;
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that I added was the:

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, fp))
{
    if(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
....
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `fgetc()` loop reads until EOF, so there won't be any more lines for the `fgets()` loop to read.

Comment: You're also never using `buffer`, so this causes the inner loop to skip the first line.

Comment: Basically, you need to change the inner loop so it processes the data in `buffer` instead of reading from the file by itself.

Comment: BTW, why do you subtract 1 from `sizeof(buffer)`?

Comment: @barrmar the reason I take minus one from it, is to account for the null terminator

Comment: `fgets()` already accounts for that, you don't have to.